# Windows 8 App Webview extract cookies

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have a webview in my windows 8 app.  Is there a way to access the cookies from the webview?  I used cookiecontainer to get response cookies but i would like to get access to cookie jar of the webview.  If not possible, can I access local folders?

I found that cookies are stored for each app locally in folder:

Metro App Cookies
%Root%\Users\%User%\AppData\Local\Packages\
%MetroAppName%\AC\INetCookies
Contains cookie files specific to each Metro App. Data is contained in a text file.

Is there a way to access the contents from the app programatically?

I'll try the following in a bit:

```
using Windows.Storage;

StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

Update:  I tried looking for the above folder INetCookies but it doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

the reality is the folder for cookies does exist if you go and search for it in the AppData\Local\Packages\PACKAGE_NAME folder if u go and search for it. But according to Microsoft's policy we are unable to access all the data in the PACKAGE_NAME folder.

Only folders we can access are the Local State, Temporary state and the Permanent State but the cookies are saved in AppData\Local\Packages\PACKAGE_NAME\AC\INetCache\SOME_KIND_OF_NAME folder which is not accessible from a metro app.

You can Go through the MSDN links below for further clearance if required :

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native InternetGetCookieEx call

```
const int INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 0x00002000;

[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(string pchURL, string pchCookieName, StringBuilder pchCookieData, ref System.UInt32 pcchCookieData, int dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);

static string InternetGetCookieEx(string url)
{
    uint sizeInBytes = 0;
    InternetGetCookieEx(url, null, null, ref sizeInBytes, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, IntPtr.Zero);
    uint bufferCapacityInChars = (uint)Encoding.Unicode.GetMaxCharCount((int)sizeInBytes);
    var cookieData = new StringBuilder((int)bufferCapacityInChars);
    InternetGetCookieEx(url, null, cookieData, ref bufferCapacityInChars, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, IntPtr.Zero);
    return cookieData.ToString();
}
```